# GPU passthrough /DDA for RTX 4080 for Windows guest on Hypervisor-V

Tags: graphics-card, virtualization, gpu, vmware, hyper-v

I have an Nvidia 4080 RTX 12GB, in an laptop installed on windows 11 pro with 13900 CPU and 64 GB Ram. The CPU also has integrated Intel xe graphics. I tested in Vmware workstation 17 pro graphic intense applications. Unfortunately, VMware does not support GPU passthrough, only vGPU and the performance for the graphics application was not amazing.
I am wondering if I could use the dedicated graphics of the RTX 4080 in Hyper V to get a performance increase?
Also I am.asking myself:

-Is the GPU I have compatible for passthrough?
-Can the host system solely work with the integrated graphics?

I've found instructions here but I would be thankful if someone could help out with their own experience on this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/deploy/deploying-graphics-devices-using-dda

Edit, Changan Auto mentioned:
https://github.com/jamesstringerparsec/Easy-GPU-PV

https://www.techtarget.com/searchvirtualdesktop/tip/Running-GPU-passthrough-for-a-virtual-desktop-with-Hyper-V

Comment: Not applicable to hybrid graphics in laptops.

Comment: Even not unter Linux with KVM?

Comment: OS doesn't matter.

Comment: Does [this article](https://www.techtarget.com/searchvirtualdesktop/tip/Running-GPU-passthrough-for-a-virtual-desktop-with-Hyper-V) help?

Comment: @harrymc I doesn't. Desktops with more than one graphics card can do it (need one for th host); Servers with only one can do it (running headless); laptops with hybrid graphics can't.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Laptops with hybrid graphics can do that with GPU Paravirtualization, just not with some NVIDIA models. See [Easy-GPU-PV](https://github.com/jamesstringerparsec/Easy-GPU-PV).

Comment: @harrymc I am wondering: Is here a direct network connection between host and guest necessary? How relates this to a safety concept when isolation between guest and host is necessary?

Comment: Just a note: Harry mentioned Easy-GPU-PV, not me (you should correct your last edit). I don't recommend any experiments with laptops such as the suggested above, all the opposite. But it's your hardware, you do you.